# Export a set up virtual machine from cloud infrastructure to use it locally

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualization

I need to perform some machine learning tasks using a Tensor Flow based Neuronal network architecture (PointNet https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet). I would like to use cloud infrastructure to do this, because I do not have the physical resources needed. The demands of the customer are, that they would like to get the whole set up machine I used for the training afterward and not only the final model. This is because they are researchers and would like to use the machine themselves, play around and understand what I did but they do not want to do the setup/installation work on their own. Unfortunately they can not provide a (physical or virtual) machine themselves right now.

The question is: Is it possible/reasonable to set up a machine on a cloud infrastructure provider like google cloud or AWS, install the needed software (which uses Nvidia Cuda) and export this machine after a while when suitable hardware is available, import it to a virtualisation tool (like Virtual Box) and continue the usage on ones own system? Will the installed GPU/Cuda-related software like TensorFlow etc. still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's possible, but it will be needed to configure the specific hardware to make it work on the local environment.

For Google Cloud Platform,
[the introduction to Deep Learning Containers](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/introducing-deep-learning-containers-consistent-and-portable-environments),  will you allow to create portable environments.

> [Deep Learning Containers](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs) are a set of Docker containers with key data science frameworks, libraries, and tools pre-installed. These containers provide you with performance-optimized, consistent environments that can help you prototype and implement workflows quickly. Learn more.

In addition, please check [Running Instances with GPU accelerators](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-gpus)

> Google provides a seamless experience for users to run their GPU workloads within Docker containers on Container-Optimized OS VM instances so that users can benefit from other Container-Optimized OS features such as security and reliability as well.

To configure Docker with Virtualbox, please check this [external blog](https://linuxhint.com/setup_docker_machine_virtualbox/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pit. The situation has changed and the client provided a machine now, so I will not test your suggestion in practice, even tough it looks appropriate. For those reason I accepted the answer.